# .htaccess hide GET value but keep their values

Tags: php, .htaccess

So, say that my URL would be this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?action=about
```

How would I get this shown like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php
```

The GET value must be kept, is there a way of doing this? I have tried multiple ways but can't really figure it out.

Comment: It make sense when you say `http://somewebsite.com/about ` but not `http://somewebsite.com/index.php`.

Comment: Well it is because i basicly have my index page, and within it i include a frame containing the content i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't pass data in the URL without having the data in the URL.

You could hide the data in a POST body, a cookie, etc … but you shouldn't. Linking is the lifeblood of the WWW and you need proper URLs to your pages that can be linked to.

Comment: Then I guess im forced to use POST however, thats pretty undoable with the ammount of a hrefs I have.

Comment: If you use POST then the data will still be visible to the user if they want to look for it. Just use regular links. Don't try to keep the addresses of pages secret from users. They can visit the pages, so the location of the page shouldn't be a secret.

Comment: It's not because im trying to keep it secret, its just because I will get really long URLS with multiple GET values.

Comment: Look URLs are not a problem. Just don't worry about them.